Some app launcher icons get borders in Suggestions, while others do not. How to control this behavior?
In this screenshot, you can see that while the Chrome launcher icon fills its entire region, my app icon has a border forced around it, reducing my icon image. How can I control this behavior in my app to avoid the border, similar to Chrome?
I have provided circular Mip Maps for android:roundIcon for hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi. I also have an anydpy-v26 version which is square - is it being cropped to make room for the border perhaps?

